# jQuery & Firefox: only the first statement of the function is executed

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to jQuery and I used the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#verlichting').click(function(){

      $('#content').html($('#contentverlichting').html());                              
      content.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      $('#content').width('1017px');                            
      $("#verlichtingHELPONCLICK").animate({height:'42px'}, "fast");
      $("#sieradenHELPONCLICK").animate({height:'33px'}, "fast");
      $("#modelbouwHELPONCLICK").animate({height:'33px'}, "fast");
      $("#opdrachtenHELPONCLICK").animate({height:'33px'}, "fast");
      $("#infoHELPONCLICK").animate({height:'33px'}, "fast");
   });

});
</script>
```

It is used to change a couple of css properties. What these properties are does not really matter: when I open my page with javescript only the first of all the statements is executed. When I change the order of the statements, again only the first in line will be executed. I am already spending a lot of time on solving the problem but I cannot find the solution.

Somebody who can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `content`? is there any error in your browser console

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define `content`. Replace

```
content.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

with

```
$("#content").css("background-color","white");
```

and it will work.

Comment: Pff thanks a lot! I feel stupid; typically a case where I looked too long for difficult solutions..

Answer (score 0):

You have to define content first

```
var content = $("#content");
content.style.backgroundColor = "white";
```

Comment: But while accessing the Javascript object you should read the first element from the collection. like `content[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to store the " $('#content') " into variable(content).
After that you can use content directly in your code.

In this way you can store:

```
var content = $("#content");

OR

content = $("#content");
```